# multiple definition of enumeration

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

I have a enumerations named Color, Return_main_menue and Playertype in including.h like so:

```
enum Color { Red, Orange, Grey, Blue, Green, White, Purple };
enum Return_main_menue { Start, Credits, Help };
enum Playertype { Computer, Human };
```

I've also a source file named tools.cpp plus the tools.h
tools.h:

```
#include "including.h"
Return_main_menue mainmenue();
```

tools.cpp:

```
Return_main_menue mainmenue()
{
// function which return Start, Credits or Help
}
```

I use the  mainmenue() in my main.cpp:

```
Return_main_menue mainm = mainmenue();
```

But the compiler returns the error:

```
.../einbindung.h:7: error: multiple definition of 'enum Farbe'
.../einbindung.h:7: error: previous definition here
and so on for the other enums
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290026/linking-h-files-with-c-with-ifdef-header-guards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) or `#pragma once` in headers to prevent multiple definitions in the same translation unit.